# Method or Variable type is Collections in Visio's Class diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007, microsoft-visio-2003

I am drawing a class diagram currently, in which there are variables of 'Collections' type and also methods that return 'Collections'.

I am unable to find any Collections type from the list given in it. I am currently using Visio 2007.

For example: `Map model` is my variable, `myMethod(): Map` is my method;

Can anyone please help me find the collections type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming by collection, you are meaning generics like List<>

Double click the class to open properties.

Click on operations to see the methods

Select the return type which closely matches what you want. EG, I've selected string as I want my parameter to be List. Now click properties.

You can set prefix and suffix which will put the words either side of the predefined type.

EG, in prefix I would type List< and in suffix I would type >

[image]

Comment: yes by saying collections I meant list, set or map. I already gave an example with Map.